# Why won't this simple @State (SwiftUI on MacOS) example update the View?

Tags: macos, swiftui, swift5

Xcode 14.1 (14B47b), Ventura 13.0.1, Swift 5

When clicking the button, it prints consecutive numbers in the debug window, but the SwiftUI View does not update.  I couldn't get it to work on a much more complicated app and ran into this problem.  Then I reduced it to this test project, and it still dosn't work.

This should be a trivial use of @State.
This is for a SwiftUI app running on MacOS.

What am I doing wrong (other than losing my mind)?

```
import SwiftUI

var globalCounter:Int = 0

@main
struct State_TestApp: App {
    init() {
        globalCounter = 1
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(counter:globalCounter)
        }
    }
}

func addOne()  {
    globalCounter += 1
    print(globalCounter)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var counter:Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add one") {
                addOne()
            }
            Text("\(counter)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(counter:globalCounter)
    }
}
```

Comment: Because a global variable cannot trigger `View` updates and because `counter` isn't being updated, `@State var counter:Int` is a source of truth that is being initialized with the value from `globalCounter` there is no connection between them. Global variables and functions are bad practice overall they should never used.

Comment: @State is supposed to make the view NOT own the storage.  This is a quote from the Apple docs: "If you pass a state property to a child view, SwiftUI updates the child any time the value changes in the parent, but the child can’t modify the value".  When ContentView is called, it is supposed to be binding the variable passed, with the value in the View.

Comment: "If you pass a state property to a child view">>>> **from the state to the child** not from some other variable to a state. There is no binding between the global and the state just an initial value.

Comment: Can you point me in the general direction to modify the counter variable (which per Apple guidelines should be marked private) from a function external to the view?

Comment: The variable shouldn't be modified from globals. Use architecture to modify values from other points in the app.

Comment: @lorem - Thank you very much.  It is scary how incorrect my perception has been for a very long time.  I now understand why the question got two downvotes, and I have fixed my code.  Would it be best to post the answer, or to delete the question?

Comment: It is up to you, deleting the question doesn't counteract the downvotes. they still stick with your profile. Look into VIPER, MVVM, MVC, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for those that want to do something similar.

```
@main
struct State_TestApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(start:3)
        }
    }
}

func addOne(number:Int) -> Int {
    return number + 1
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    init(start:Int) {
        counter = start
    }
    
    @State private var counter:Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add one") {
                counter = addOne(number: counter)
            }
            Text("\(counter)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(start:4)
    }
}
```